# Defining a homeomorphism from an equivalence relation on a covering map domain to its image.

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

If $p: \tilde Y \to Y$ is a covering map, and we define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\tilde Y$ by $\tilde y_1 \sim \tilde y_2$ if $P(\tilde y_1) = p(\tilde y_2)$.

How would you show that the quotient space $\tilde Y / \sim$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

Answer (score 2):

The covering map is well defined as a map from $\tilde{Y} / \sim$ to $Y$. More precisely, if $\pi : \tilde{Y} \to \tilde{Y}/ \sim$ is the canonical projection, there exists $\tilde{p} : \tilde{Y}/\sim \to Y$ such that $\tilde{p} \circ \pi = p$.

You can show that $\tilde{p}$ is precisely a homeomorphism.